# How to use LIKE Operator in LINQ to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-like

I'm using Entity Framework.

**Problem:** search a name that start with 'a' in a list of strings:

```
var likeQuery = from k in dbContext.Categories  
                where sqlMethod.Like(k.CategoryName, "a%" )  // name start with a 
                select k;
        
foreach (var item in likeQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Item.);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this.

```
var result 
  = dbContext.Categories.Where(i => i.CategoryName.StartsWith("a")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! :)
What if a want First name from Result list.
using FirstOrDefault(); i tried at end of of ToList() but it say error. plz help

Answer (score 0):

If this is `EF Core` than the following can be used.

```
public static  List<Categories> CategoriesLike(string keyword)
{
    using var dbContext = new NorthwindContext();

    return dbContext.Categories.Where(category => 
        EF.Functions.Like(category.CategoryName, $"{keyword}%"))
        .ToList();
}
```